# Angular Material Design text size change

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ to make my site responsive. For different screen sizes, I want my font size to change for example,

for small screen, I want font size to be 5px and for greater than medium, 14px.

I have done this so far but font size does not change:

```
<h3 class=".md-display-1">John</h3>
```

its css:

```
@media (max-width: @flex-sm) {
  body{font-size: 2px;}
}

@media (max-width: @flex-gt-md) {
  body{font-size: 30px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some issue with your code.

0 - You are NOT using the class:

```
 <h3 class=".md-display-1">John</h3>
```

You must change it to:

```
 <h3 class="md-display-1">John</h3>
```

Without the dot. The dot is only to indicate it is a class. And when is id we use #.

1 - You are using variables in CSS. The CSS doesn't support variables. Less/Sass support variables. But if you are using css. You must write the sizes. The standard sizes in Bootstrap are:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
@media (max-width:767px) {
  body {font-size: 2px;}
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width:768px) {
  body {font-size: 10px;}
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width:992px) {
  body {font-size: 20px;}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width:1200px) {
  body {font-size: 30px;}
}
```

2 - Remember use AngularMaterial CSS. They include the Tipography docs in its page: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/typography . Check there. They use 10px as base. And use em to expand based on clasess.

Comment: so as per point (1) thats using bootstrap, if I wanted to do angular way then how would that work? as you suggested bootstrap but I'm using angular material

Comment: I didn't use the Bootstrap way. I used for example, to let you know about the sizes of the devices screens. 

The angular way is not about it. Angular is about Javascript. And style is about CSS. In your case you must write the sizes by pixels. Not by Variables (or you must use something like Less or Sass.

If you wanna see the different options size in angular material you can check: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container

They have: `layout-xs: width < 600px`, `layout-sm 600px <= width < 960px`,  `layout-md 960px <= width < 1280px`, `layout-lg 1280px <= width < 1920px`